# Bootstrap Navbar breaks on Responsive page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've converted a project into being responsive using Bootstrap. The project can be viewed on http://homareno.com/

The responsive `nabvar` breaks on **mobile** view on one page only: http://homareno.com/usa.php

On that page I have to use a secondary CSS file provided by the client which is:
http://homareno.com/ResponsiveSearchForm/default.css

There seems to be a conflict there as the nav class has been re-used, however removing or renaming the class on the css file breaks the search form within the page.

Comment: your default.css sets among others `mainMenu ul { display: block !important; }` which makes your menu visible always. Also the html structure differs no title for the menu (why the toggle is missing too?) etc. Using `!important` is not a good idea too, see also https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Answer (score 0):

I have some tips for you:

**1:**

What is `title` tag after `header` tag? You have to use `title tag` in `<HEAD>` tag.

**2:**

In `default.css:256` you have this:

```
header, .resp-accordion {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Remove `display:none` or change to `block`.

**3:**

In `default.css:386` you have this codes:

```
.mainMenu ul {
    display: block !important;
    top: 0 !important;
}
```

Remove `top` and `display` attributes.